# review audit failed "Understand" Button closes the rewiew

Tags: support, review

I just got the message, that I should look over my review again [here](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/327758) but when I clicked "I understand" it was closed.

This is not what I wanted, I wanted to look over it again to improve my work

Please let me revise my review somehow

Comment: You can't redo audits...

Answer (score 1):

The review is shown *while* the Understand button is visible. If you'd like to view it again *after* hitting "I Understand", just hit your browser's "back" button - it'll still be in your history.

Comment: no. I am punished for hitting "I understand" ;) If I go back, I am not in the review mode any more

Comment: @rubo77 Look through this: http://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/history